The subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ distinct elements of group $G$ such that $a,b$ have order $2$ and $ab$ finite order is isomorphic to $D_{2n}$
This is a problem from Aluffi's textbook on algebra.
$a,b\in G$ are distinct and $\lvert a\rvert = \lvert b \rvert = 2$ and $\lvert ab\rvert = n\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to show that the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a,b$ is isomorphic to $D_{2n}$.
I already know that $\langle a,b\mid a^2,b^2, (ab)^n\rangle$ is a presentation for $D_{2n}$, and want to use this fact.
Consider the inclusion map $\iota: \{a,b\}\to G$ and the canonical map $\iota^\star: \{a,b\}\to F(\{a,b\})$ the free group on two generators. Then by definition, the subgroup generated by $a,b$ in $G$ is defined as the image of the unique homomorphism $\varphi:F(\{a,b\})\to G$ such that $\varphi\circ\iota^\star = \iota$.
My plan was to show that $\ker\varphi = \langle\langle a^2, b^2, (ab)^n\rangle\rangle$ the normal closure of these words, and then deduce that $F(\{a,b\})/\ker\varphi \cong \textrm{im}(\varphi)$.
Showing that $\ker\varphi \supseteq \langle\langle a^2, b^2, (ab)^n\rangle\rangle$ is immediate, however the other direction is unclear. I feel like I always get tripped up on this sort of thing when dealing with free groups. Should I reconsider my approach? Thanks


Suggestion: It's hard to show that $ker\varphi \subseteq \langle\langle a^2, b^2, (ab)^n\rangle\rangle$ directly, because you have no proper tools to deal with the normal closure of a set of relations, at least for now(You may meet the same problem when you learn tensor product). The standard method avoiding to compute
relations is as follows:

Now, you have a surjective homomorphism:
$$D_{2n} \cong \frac{F(\{a,b\})}{\langle\langle a^2, b^2, (ab)^n\rangle\rangle} \xrightarrow{f} G$$
To prove that $f$ is injective, it's sufficed to verify that $|G| \ge 2n$.
Since $|ab|=n$, we have $|G| \ge n$. If $G$ is only a cyclic group of order $n$,  then $G$ cannot have two distinct elements of order $2$, contradiction! So we can claim that $|G| \ge 2n$. Since $|D_{2n}| = 2n$, and $f$ is surjective, $f$ must be injective.

Ahhh I see. I wanted to show that G had at least $2n$ elements but was having trouble. Now that you’ve shown how to use the info that there are 2 distinct elements of order 2, it makes sense! Thank you

That is clever.

Hint
You've got an element of order $2,$ and one of order $n.$  Also $a(ab)a=a^2ba=ba=(ab)^{-1},$ since $ab(ba)=1.$
Those are the right relations.
To ice it you might want to use von Dyck's theorem. You should be able to get an isomorphism out of it.
Edit:  actually,  using the anti-commutativity relation (the last one), you can prove there are only $2n$ elements, as maybe another way.

Thank you for the pointer to von Dyck’s theorem, that has proven extremely helpful

I think we can only obtain a surjective homomorphism $f: \langle a,b\mid a^2,b^2, (ab)^n\rangle \to G$ by von Dyck's theorem, rather than an isomorphism(It's difficult to compute $ker(f)$ directly). What is the "anti-commutativity relation"? I am sorry for my poor English, I may misunderstand something.

It's the relation $aca=c^{-1},$ where $c=ab.$  With this we can get that everything is of the form $a^kc^m.$  It follows that there's at most $2n$ elements.   So that the surjection is an isomorphism.   @ShuningZhang

@non-euclideangeometry To prove that $f$ is isomorphism, I think we need to show that $|G| \ge 2n$, rather than $|G| \le 2n$(It's already illustrated by the surjectivity of $f$).

Oh yeah,  right,  I had my arrows reversed.  This is not too difficult though.   @ShuningZhang
